# set dynamic keys on update mongodb

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have mongoDB `companies` collection

```
c00:
    {
        _id: c00,
        name: 'acme',
        results: [
            0: { _id: 'a10', name: 'foo', visible: true },
            1: { _id: 'a11', name: 'bar', visible: false }
        ],
    },
c01:
    {
        _id: c01,
        name: 'apra'
        results: [
            0: { _id: 'b10', name: 'foo', visible: false },
            1: { _id: 'b11', name: 'bar', visible: true },
            2: { _id: 'b12', name: 'qux', visible: true },
        ]
    }
}
```

I need query that modify

`company.c01.results` with resultId === 'b11'`

to

`{ _id: 'b11', name: 'bar', visible: false }`

I have tried

```
  CompanyModel
    .update(
      { [`${companyId}.results`]: resultsId },
      {
        $set: { ['results.$.visible']: false },
      }
    )
```

but this didn't work.
Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 4):

You need to put the dynamic key at the time of `$set` as well

```
CompanyModel.update(
  { [`${companyId}.results._id`]: resultsId },
  { $set: { [`${companyId}.results.$.visible`]: false }}
)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
CompanyModel.update(
    { "company.c01.sets._id": "b11" }, 
    { "$set": { "company.$.c01.visible": false } }
)
```